# transpose multiple columns Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reshape a dataframe, but I'm not able to get the results I need.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
    m   r   s   p   O       W       N         
    1   4   3   1   2.81    3.70    3.03  
    1   4   4   1   2.14    2.82    2.31  
    1   4   5   1   1.47    1.94    1.59  
    1   4   3   2   0.58    0.78    0.60  
    1   4   4   2   0.67    0.00    0.00
    1   4   5   2   1.03    2.45    1.68
    1   4   3   3   1.98    1.34    1.81
    1   4   4   3   0.00    0.04    0.15
    1   4   5   3   0.01    0.00    0.26
```

I need to reshape the dataframe so it will look like this:

```
    m   r   s   p   O       W       N      p    O       W       N     p  O      W       N
    1   4   3   1   2.81    3.70    3.03   2    0.58    0.78    0.60  3  1.98   1.34    1.81
    1   4   4   1   2.14    2.82    2.31   2    0.67    0.00    0.00  3 0.00    0.04    0.15
    1   4   5   1   1.47    1.94    1.59   2    1.03    2.45    1.68  3 0.01    0.00    0.26
```

I tried to use the `pivot_table` function

```
df.pivot_table(index=['m','r','s'], columns=['p'], values=['O','W','N'])
```

but I'm not able to get quite what I want. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone who fancies himself as pretty handy with pandas, the `pivot_table` and `melt` functions are confusing to me. I prefer to stick with a well-defined and unique index and use the `stack` and `unstack` methods of the dataframe itself.

First, I'll ask if you really need to repeat the p-column like that? I can sort of see its value when presenting data, but IMO pandas isn't really set up to work like that. We could shoehorn it in, but let's see if a simpler solution gets you what you need.

Here's what I would do:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datatable = StringIO("""\
    m   r   s   p   O       W       N         
    1   4   3   1   2.81    3.70    3.03  
    1   4   4   1   2.14    2.82    2.31  
    1   4   5   1   1.47    1.94    1.59  
    1   4   3   2   0.58    0.78    0.60  
    1   4   4   2   0.67    0.00    0.00
    1   4   5   2   1.03    2.45    1.68
    1   4   3   3   1.98    1.34    1.81
    1   4   4   3   0.00    0.04    0.15
    1   4   5   3   0.01    0.00    0.26""")

df = (
    pandas.read_table(datatable, sep='\s+')
          .set_index(['m', 'r', 's', 'p'])
          .unstack(level='p')
)

df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
df.sort(axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
p         1                 2                 3            
          O     W     N     O     W     N     O     W     N
m r s                                                      
1 4 3  2.81  3.70  3.03  0.58  0.78  0.60  1.98  1.34  1.81
    4  2.14  2.82  2.31  0.67  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.04  0.15
    5  1.47  1.94  1.59  1.03  2.45  1.68  0.01  0.00  0.26
```

So now the columns are a MultiIndex and you can access, for example, all of the values where `p = 2` with `df[2]` or `df.xs(2, level='p', axis=1)`, which gives me:

```
          O     W     N
m r s                  
1 4 3  0.58  0.78  0.60
    4  0.67  0.00  0.00
    5  1.03  2.45  1.68
```

Similarly, you can get all of the `W` columns with: `df.xs('W', level=1, axis=1)`
(we say `level=1`) because that column level does not have a name, so we use its position instead)

```
p         1     2     3
m r s                  
1 4 3  3.70  0.78  1.34
    4  2.82  0.00  0.04
    5  1.94  2.45  0.00
```

You can similarly query the columns by using `axis=0`.

If you *really* need the `p` values in a column, just add it there manually and reindex your columns:

```
for p in df.columns.get_level_values('p').unique():
    df[p, 'p'] = p

cols = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3], list('pOWN')])
df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
print(df)

       1                    2                    3                  
       p     O     W     N  p     O     W     N  p     O     W     N
m r s                                                               
1 4 3  1  2.81  3.70  3.03  2  0.58  0.78  0.60  3  1.98  1.34  1.81
    4  1  2.14  2.82  2.31  2  0.67  0.00  0.00  3  0.00  0.04  0.15
    5  1  1.47  1.94  1.59  2  1.03  2.45  1.68  3  0.01  0.00  0.26
```

Comment: I see what you did there, however this is the last step of a small script that i wrote and i need the output to look they way i mentioned. If pandas is not the tool to do this, what would you recommend using to manipulate the dataframe to get the desired output?

Comment: great this is working the way i need it. I will take a closer look to all the functions you used to get a better idea on how they work.

Comment: @Daniel `stack` -> `melt`; `unstack` -> `pivot`, but they don't aggregate the data in any way and only operate on the row and column labels (indices)

Answer (score 0):

```
    b = open('ss2.csv', 'w')
    a = csv.writer(b)
    sk = ''
    with open ('df_col2.csv', 'r') as ann:
        for col in ann:
            an = col.lower().strip('\n').split(',')
            suk += an[0] + ','
    sk = sk[:-2]
    a.writerow([sk])
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of what your code does and why it answers the question.